# std::ofstream does not accept const char * for << operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, ofstream

I've upgraded my C++ project from VS 2010 to 2015 and have some problems compiling it. Method header looks like following:

```
void CCodeGenerator::GenerateCode(const MachineExArray & AMachineExArray,
    const MachineArrays & AMachineArrays,
    std::ofstream & HeaderFile,
    std::ofstream & SourceFile)
```

There's a line:

```
std::string HeaderDefine = path(OutputFilename).filename().generic_string();

for (std::string::iterator Iter = HeaderDefine.begin(); Iter != HeaderDefine.end(); Iter++)
    *Iter = toupper((unsigned char)*Iter);

HeaderDefine = "__" + HeaderDefine + "_H__";

HeaderFile << "#ifndef " << HeaderDefine << "\n"; // <-- This one
```

Compiler stops here and says:

> No operator "<<" matches these operands. Operand types are:
>   std::ofstream << const char[9]

I wrote in C++ long ago, but from what I remember, `std::ofstream` is quite liberal and should accept most of simple types as input. Where's the problem?

---

When, at the beginning I write `HeaderFile.`, It is immediately marked as error (red underline) and comment says, "Incomplete types are not allowed".

Comment: What is a `HeaderDefine`?

Comment: HeaderDefine is std::string.

Comment: Humour me for a moment and replace `HeaderDefine` with `HeaderDefine.c_str()`, then see if the compile error changes to something clearer.

Comment: make sure you have got `#include <ostream>`

Comment: @Bathsheba, nothing happened, the same error. I've got like 500 lines like this later, each one with exactly the same error.

Comment: @M.M I've got `#include <iostream>` in header file. Adding `#include <ostream>` didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: See if you can make a MCVE that gives the same error

Comment: It *has* to be a missing `#include` then surely?

Comment: Maybe clean and rebuild your project;, the symptoms are consistent with `ostream` not being included so perhaps something has gone wrong with the precompiled headers or something like that. Try having the include actually in the .cpp file, in case there is a circular dependency in headers

Comment: @Bathsheba, found it. In this single file I'm including `<filesystem>`, which seem to have changed (because some `path` methods, like `file_string()` doesn't work anymore). It must have had included `<fstream>`, so the code worked. I had only to add this one and file compiles. Thanks!

Comment: While you're at it, double-underscores are forbidden in all code that is not part of the standard library implementation, so you probably shouldn't generate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An observation on the

> "Incomplete types are not allowed"

. error.

```
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream HeaderFile;
}
```

gives this error too, while this

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream HeaderFile;
}
```

compiles in VS2015.